# MySQLi Escape String

Tags: mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

Every time I try mysql(i)_real_escape_string the value put into the MySQL table cell is empty. Always. Anyone help? I use the object orientated version of it and I tried the exactly same code with that function and without it, and it worked perfectly when it was not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three rules to get it right:

1. do not use this function in the application code
2. do not put your variables directly into query but use **prepared statements**
3. do not use raw mysqli in the application code but use some higher level abstraction, at least [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Comment: So I can't use it inside the $db->query( In here? );